# Python BeautifulSoup replace img src

Tags: python, html, href, src

I'm trying to parse HTML content from site, change a href and img src. A href changed successful, but img src don't.

It changed in variable but not in HTML (post_content):

```
<p><img alt="alt text" src="https://lifehacker.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/15120903sa_d2__1471520915-630x523.jpg" title="Title"/></p>
```

Not _http://site.ru...

```
<p><img alt="alt text" src="http://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/15120903sa_d2__1471520915-630x523.jpg" title="Title"/></p>
```

My code

```
if "app-store" not in url:
        r = requests.get("https://lifehacker.ru/2016/08/23/kak-vybrat-trimmer/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        post_content = soup.find("div", {"class", "post-content"})
        for tag in post_content():
            for attribute in ["class", "id", "style", "height", "width", "sizes"]:
                del tag[attribute]

        for a in post_content.find_all('a'):
            a['href'] = a['href'].replace("https://lifehacker.ru", "http://site.ru")

        for img in post_content.find_all('img'):
            img_urls = img['src']
            if "https:" not in img_urls:
                img_urls="http:{}".format(img_urls)
            thumb_url = img_urls.split('/')
            urllib.urlretrieve(img_urls, "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/{}/{}".format(folder_name, thumb_url[-1]))

            file_url = "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/{}/{}".format(folder_name, thumb_url[-1])
            data = {
                'name': '{}'.format(thumb_url[-1]),
                'type': 'image/jpeg',
            }

            with open(file_url, 'rb') as img:
                data['bits'] = xmlrpc_client.Binary(img.read())


            response = client.call(media.UploadFile(data))

            attachment_url = response['url']


            img_urls = img_urls.replace(img_urls, attachment_url)



        [s.extract() for s in post_content('script')]
        post_content_insert = bleach.clean(post_content)
        post_content_insert = post_content_insert.replace('&lt;', '<')
        post_content_insert = post_content_insert.replace('&gt;', '>')

        print post_content_insert
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're never assigning `img_urls` back to `img['src']`. Try doing that at the end of the block.

```
img_urls = img_urls.replace(img_urls, attachment_url)
img['src'] = img_urls
```

... But first, you need to change your `with` statement so it uses some name other than `img` for your file object. Right now you're overshadowing the dom element and you can no longer access it.

```
        with open(file_url, 'rb') as some_file:
            data['bits'] = xmlrpc_client.Binary(some_file.read())
```

Comment: Already tried but  -  img['src'] = img_urls
TypeError: 'file' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Oh, it's a name collision issue. Edited.

Comment: Working - perfect, thanks a lot, and sorry for noob questions.